# In ASP.NET Core Identity, what is a ticket?

Tags: asp.net-core

I've read the docs (for days) but I still haven't a clue what a ticket (`AuthenticationTicket`) is or what it does.

It's not a term I recognise from the language of OpenID or OAuth but its a main concept in the Identity framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The auth ticket is a stamped auth session id or principal. Rather than just being the principal, for example, the stamp allows the ticket to be invalidated, essentially rendering the data indecipherable and useless. This invalidation would occur on some schedule, requiring a new ticket to be issued to continue to maintain authenticated state, potentially forcing a new authentication (login).

Long and short, it's an abstraction for the purpose of persistence, such as when using cookie auth, to prevent the data from having an infinite lifetime where it can be deciphered. It also provides a way to invalidate an authenticated session without having to actually depend on the cookie being deleted. Once the server has invalidated the ticket, the cookie could live forever on the client, but it will no longer be good, and the user will be forced to re-authenticated.